# alert with delay after scroll

Tags: javascript, scroll

Is there a simple technique to make a scroll function with a delay on this?
for example: if an users scroll 100px down, wait 2 seconds and run function down (the same for scroll up).

The overflow from the body is hidden!

```
body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

I am looking for plain javascript.

```
function up() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function down() {
   document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

Comment: Show the code you've written

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Unfortunately, requesting code is off-topic.

Comment: Provide a code snippet so we can see what you have archived this far and we will help you archive your goal. Or else all of us can provide different approaches and solutions which might not apply to your current code. And as previous commenter stated, code requesting is off-topic.

Comment: I changed my question!

Answer (score 0):

Most things  you need to do "based on user behaviour" means tapping into the associated page event(s), and then looking at the event data to determine what to do next, so:

Use `window.addEventListener("scroll", checkScroll)` with a function called `checkScroll(evt)` that checks the `evt` data for the direction in which the user scrolled, and then based on that information call the actual function you want to trigger, using `setTimeout` to effect the delay.

Comment: I think that dealy is the wrong word for my question.

Comment: If the user scroll down 100px activate function down. How can i make this?

Comment: "wait 2 seconds and run function" is a 2 second delay. If that is not what you mean, please reword your original question?

Answer (score 0):

But this do not work if the overflow is hidden right? How can Javascript know how much

Comment: I think he means like a function as fullpage. There is no scrollbar but the scroll up and down trigger functions ;)

Comment: Yes  i am looking for this, but with my own functions.